# field renders with 2 spaces

Tags: theming

In a template I'd like to get an html tag from a field:

```
<?php print '<' . render($content['field_headline_format']) . '>'; ?>
```

This should render  or  depending on the value of the field. But before the value it renders 2 spaces: <  h2>.

I have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: Are you sure they're spaces? Have you checked the source?

Comment: Yes. Spaces. 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php print '<' . trim(render($content['field_headline_format'])) . '>'; ?>
```